# Django - Create model instance for bulk_create

Tags: python, django

For example I want add to db 1 million entries (more than 400mb), that i read from file and append entries into the array and if array length more then 1000 I call `bulk_create`, but this script with memory leak.. Why?..

```
# python 3
# models.py 
class Item(models.Model):
    name1 = models.TextField()
    name2 = models.TextField()
    name3 = models.TextField()
    name4 = models.TextField()
    name5 = models.TextField()
    name6 = models.TextField()
    name7 = models.TextField()
    name8 = models.CharFiled(max_length=150, unique=True)

# action
with open('items.txt') as file_object: 
    items = []
    for line in file_object:
        item_data = line.strip().split(';')

        i = Item(
            name1=item_data[0],
            name2=item_data[1],
            name3=item_data[2],
            name4=item_data[3],
            name5=item_data[4],
            name6=item_data[5],
            name7=item_data[6],
            name8=item_data[7],
            name9=item_data[8],
        )

        items.append(i)

        if len(items) > 1000: 
            Item.objects.bulk_create(items)
            del items[:]
```

---

And sometimes script raise error

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Lost connection to MySQL server at '127.0.0.1:3306', system error: 10054

Why?..

---

Before, i was using SQLAlchemy and such problems were not.

Comment: This may not be the reason for the error, but it seems to me that you're calling bulk_create within the for-loop, but you probably want to call it after the for-loop has run?

Comment: @kreld if i will be keep all (more than 1 million) model instance in one variable, will be loaded into memory more than 700mb. It is for this reason i call `bulk_create` after 1000 items.

Comment: maybe you can try to use a generator instead of for-loop?

Comment: @AndreyZarubin can you show example?.. And why it maybe help me with memory leak?

Comment: @AndreyZarubin because i can create iterator, but how i can use in this case `bulk_creator`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I didn't run this code but you will get an idea

```
with open('items.txt') as file_object:
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('items.txt'))
    def _get_items():
        for counter, line in enumerate(file_object):
            item_data = line.strip().split(';')

            i = Item(
                name1=item_data[0],
                name2=item_data[1],
                name3=item_data[2],
                name4=item_data[3],
                name5=item_data[4],
                name6=item_data[5],
                name7=item_data[6],
                name8=item_data[7],
                name9=item_data[8],
            )
            yield i
            if counter == 1000:
                break

    for i in num_lines / 1000:
        Item.objects.bulk_create(_get_items())
```